# My python console closes after a while without printing any results

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script that returns a website with no characters on it out of a list. But the python console stays for about a minute, and then closes, What is wrong with the code?

```
import urllib.request
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
from time import sleep

keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)] #list of all 3letter combinations
for x in keywords:
    site = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + x)
    if site == '':
        print(site)
print("search is finished")
sleep(183708)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `print(x)` at the top of the loop, so you have an idea of the loop progress.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `urlopen()` can ever return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `pause = input()` at the end of the program so that it waits after it prints. I've faced this issue before and I tried this... It worked.